# Call to fetch_assoc() on a non-object failing?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a table in my phpMyAdmin called 'whatevers'. You can see the contents of it

[image: here]

. It has a load of what I call "blahs' in it---basically text entries (rows? columns?).

I'm trying to fetch all the entries (records?) out of this table and echo them.

This is the code I have attempted to do this with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to <? print $host; ?>!</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    </head>
    <body>

<?php
$servername = "mysql.hostinger.co.uk";
$username = "u427788796_h4x1t";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "u427788796_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

////


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `whatevers` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

//echo $sql; 

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['classtype']."<br>";
    }





mysqli_close($conn);
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is failing as I am getting the error message:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/u427788796/public_html/default.php on line 30**

Comment: you can't call the method `->fetch_assoc`, haven't even started executing the query yet

Comment: Read example 1: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: `$sql` is a string, not an object. you haven't even ran a query

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have call the method query

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `whatevers` LIMIT 0, 30 ");
```

Comment: now it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in /home/u427788796/public_html/default.php on line 30