# Need to print out object property members?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that return an object:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `whatevers` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Using `print_r ($result);` I can see that `$result` contains this data:

**mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 4 [type] => 0 )**

So I can see from this information that there is 4 entries in [num_rows] .

What I would like to do is print out those 4 things. Also, since that 4 is likely to change I need it to be able to print them out if the object contains 5, 6, 7 etc.

Comment: what happened to your code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33534205/1028804)? if you understand that code you will have your answers

Comment: i very much doubt that. the answer *you* accepted should fix your problem and thus make this question redundent as the very things you are asking to do in this question are done in your original code

Comment: There's nothing about accessing objects in that post you are referring to.
As you can see here I am approaching it in a different way.

Comment: because you clearly copy and pasted code without making an attempt to understand how it works, otherwise you would notice quite clearly that [Suchit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33537579/1028804) is more or less what `while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row['classtype']."<br>"; }` does in your original code. the only differnt way i see is that your not using OO which looking up [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) would clearly point our your accepted answer aswell

Comment: @Memor-X  'more or less' won't work for me since I am obviously new at this. Go answer some super questions if this is so far beneath you instead of being an arrogant jerk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looping the result :

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r( $row);//you can echo desired columns using column names
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I got it with this:

 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r( $row[blahs]);
        echo "<br>";

Comment: @HaxIt if you want single elements to display use  `echo $row[blahs]. "<br>";`

Comment: Oh yeah that's better.  I didn't know about the concatenation character. Everything is so different in php.